# Setting up a master database to control the structure of other databases

Tags: mysql, database

I got a case where I have several databases running on the same server. There's one database for each client (company1, company2 etc). The structure of each of these databases should be identical with the same tables etc, but the data contained in each db will be different.

What I want to do is keep a master db that will contain no data, but manage the structure of all the other databases, meaning if I add, remove or alter any tables in the master db the changes will also be mirrored out to the other databases.

Example: If a table named Table1 is created in the master DB, the other databases (company1, company2 etc) will also get a table1.

Currently it is done by a script that monitors the database logs for changes made to the master database and running the same queries on each of the other databases. Looked into database replication, but from what I understand this will also bring along the data from the master database, which is not an option in this case.

Can I use some kind of logic against database schemas to do it?

So basicly what I'm asking here is:

1. How do I make this sync happen in the best possible way? Should I use a script monitoring the logs for changes or some other method?
2. How do I avoid existing data getting corrupted if a table is altered? (data getting removed if a table is dropped is okay)
3. Is syncing from a master database considered a good way to do what I wish (having an easy maintainable structure across several datbases)?
4. How will making updates like this affect the performance of the databases?

Hope my question was clear and that this is not a duplicate of some other thread. If more information and/or a better explantion of my problem is needed, let me know:)

Comment: Possible answer on ServerFault http://serverfault.com/questions/176936/mysql-replicate-structure-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the list of tables for a given schema using:

```
select TABLE_NAME from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA='<master table name>';
```

Use this list for a script or stored procedure ala:

```
create database if not exists <name>;
use <name>;
for each ( table_name in list )
    create table if not exists <name>.table_name like <master_table>.table_name;
```

Now that Im thinking about it you might be able to put a trigger on the 'information_schema.tables' db that would call the 'create/maintain' script. Look for inserts and react accordingly.